# MongoDB Aggregation - Check the second value if the first is null in

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have this object in my products schema:

```
{
  price: {
    v1: number,
    v2: number
  }
}
```

`price.v1` is always required and not null, on the other hand, `price.v2` is not required and can be null.

I want to search the products with the price > 20.

If the `price.v2` is null, I need to check with the `price.v1 > 20`.

If the `price.v2` is **not** null, I need to check with the `price.v2 > 20`.

How can I do this in an aggregation query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work with [`$ifNull`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator. The query will filter with `price.v2` first when it is not null. Otherwise, it will use `price.v1` to filter.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$price.v2",
              "$price.v1"
            ]
          },
          20
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4v878icMXbn)